# SAS Sql Case statement - how to convert SAS data step into sql case

Tags: sas, case

I am trying to rewrite SAS data step into SAS Sql.  I keep getting syntax errors for the versions I have written so far.  The documentation and examples do not address the type of if/then I am working with.

Below is the original data step:

```
data tmp1;
set _tst1;   
if put(tin, $gp.) = 'N' and 
   (missing(npi_num) or index(npi_num,"~") >= 1) then del1=1;    
if put(tin, $gp.) = "Y" or
   put(tin, $msp.) = "Y"  or 
   put(cats(tin, npi_num), $pio.) =: "Y" or 
   put(cats(tin, npi_num), $cpc.) = 'Y' then del2=1;  
if sum(num_elig, msr_yes, num_excl, msr_no) ^gt 0 then del3=1;          
if sum(del1,del2,del3) > 0 then delete;
run;
```

Here is my attempt:

```
proc sql;
create table tst as
select *,
case
    when 
       put(tin, $gp.) = 'N' and 
       (missing(npi_num) or index(npi_num,"~") >= 1) 
        then 1
        else 0
        end as del1
    when 
       put(tin, $gp.) = "Y" or
       put(tin, $msp.) = "Y"  or 
       put(cats(tin, npi_num), $pio.) =: "Y" or 
       put(cats(tin, npi_num), $cpc.) = 'Y' 
        then 1
        else 0
        end as del2
    when 
       sum(num_eligible, msr_met, num_exclusion, msr_not_met) ^gt 0
        then 1
        else 0
        end as del3
from _tst1;
quit;
```

Comment: You are missing a couple commas after "end as del1" and "end as del2". Then you have to start a new case for each field.

Comment: You don't mention what the ERRORS are.  Why is that?  I do notice you have =: which is not allowed in SQL use EQT instead.

Comment: @RamB you were correct.  I was missing a commas between the case blocks.  It is submitting without syntax errors now.

Comment: @data_null_I fixed the =:. Thank you.